# Blackened insulation and wire on back of oven

Tags: wiring, oven

I noticed a rubber/plastic smell this morning on my oven and while trying to identify it, I took the back off the oven. I noticed two spots were blackened. This is nowhere near the smell, which I think is just old oil/grease smelling bad.

Both spots are near the two heating elements. This is the top one.
[image: Top heating element]

Here is the other.
[image: Bottom heating element]

My question: Is this just normal heat and smoke from the elements, or is something more serious? The wires are all tight and there is no noticeable burning on them, other than the darkened white one.

Edit: Extra image added by request.
[image]

Comment: A little dirt or char on high temperature insulation is normal.  It's hard to say whether the amount or position of yours is normal without knowing your oven better.  What looks odd to me is the electrically uninsulated terminals in contact with the thermal insulation, even apparently at the main 240V terminal block.  Again I don't know your oven but that seems very off.  The thermal insulation is not conductive but it can become damp or can catch and retain bits of conductive material.  Nobody would *design* something that way.

Comment: @jay613 Would you suggest I push the insulation off those terminals to try and prevent any moisture or debris from coming into contact with them?

Comment: I would look at a service manual and/or youtube videos of people repairing your *specific* model, but lacking any further information yes I would do that (turn off the power first of course).  Off the main power entry terminals.   I'm also puzzled by the first picture with metal terminals sticking through the back wall of the oven ... there's nothing you can do about that, it looks to be designed that way.

Comment: Don’t mess with the insulation on the wire! If you remove it the copper will oxidize because of the heat and air. It’s best to not mess with it. Moving the discolored thermal insulation will allow more heat to escape.

Comment: @EdBeal I think jay613 was talking about the white insulation, not the insulation on the wires themselves.

Comment: @ josh notice I mentioned both, you need the white insulation around that area to prevent the heat from escaping or getting to the wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal. The wire is high temp fixture wire and the fiberglass covering is for the wires actually entering the heated area. Those connectors are a high temp also , a normal crimp on disconnect or spade will not last, those are usually rated at over 500 deg f.
Where the most likely places are where the cord attaches to the unit 3 or 4 screws /nuts if those get loose they arc and burn. The receptacle where the outlet is connected, these are the 2 locations I have found loose connections when the stove /oven was working but smelling hot.

Comment: So basically nothing to worry about that you can see in the pictures?

Comment: @FreeMan I added a picture from a different angle.

Comment: Josh That area is normal I would not mess with it. You want the thermal insulation around the end of the cal rods that’s the heating element if the insulation is disturbed more heat will escape. For a hot wiring smell my first checks are the oven connection to the cord and the receptacle connection.